# How to include bootstrap file in my ejs files?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, ejs

So i have installed bootstrap using npm -bootstrap@3 but when i am trying to include bootstrap.min.css file from node_modules in my application, it shows this error in my console :

**error message**

[image]

In the network tab it shows

> 404 not found on the bootstrap source.

Below are some images on my project structue:

**project folder structure**

[image]

**ejs code to include bootstrap file**

[image]

Whats the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are building the relative path based on location of your ejs file, what actually you need to do is look at the path how ejs view is mapped and you need to make it relative form there. 
In your case its `header.ejs` and lets say you are serving it from root page it should be `../node_modules` but if you do this it will break in a different page like /posts/foo so the best way to fix your problem is keeping your css files in /public/css folder and add public folder as your static folders and use path like `/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: But if I want to preview my `ejs` without running the node server ,this file can not access to `bootstrap.min.css` .

Comment: Yes, But EJS is for SSR so it does not make much sense if you are not running Node server

Answer (score 8):

I got the same issue following this tutorial. You can solve this by express.static built-in middleware function.

1. Create a directory named public
2. Add following code to your app.js file

   app.use(express.static('public'))
3. Now you can place your bootstrap files in this directory(or subdirectory) and link them relative to public directory.

You can find more info here.
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not use from CDN?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

Comment: the bootstrap cdn link is blocked on my office laptop (shows connection tunnel error), so i'm trying to do this the hard way using npm package

Comment: Add them in views folder and you can access using ../bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to access to static files from the server and your `bootstrap.min.css` is a static file,as we know nodejs provide a way to serve static files if you are using Express.
For example,you can use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and JavaScript files in a directory named public:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

You should know that :

> Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the
>   name of the static directory is not part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and decided to give middleware like express.static() a go.

**warning**: when I declared express.static("public") I put it at the bottom of my app.js file and it didn't work for me. So I moved it up and it works.. here is the example

```
"use strict"; 

const express       = require("express"),
app                 = express();
const layouts       = require("express-ejs-layouts");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(
express.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    })
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(layouts);
app.use(express.static("public")); 

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index"); 
});

app.listen( app.get("port"), () => {console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${app.get("port")}`);
});
```

Then in public folder (where my css, js, images are), I put boostrap.css there
In layout.ejs I have html file and refer it as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>School of business</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css"> <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css"> 
</head>

<body>
```

.........

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AomTC.png)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, using Bootstrap CDN

**head.ejs**

```
> <!-- views/partials/head.ejs --> <meta charset="UTF-8" /> <title>Super
> Awesome</title>
> 
> <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS --> <link   rel="stylesheet"  
> href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
> integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
> crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Include this in **index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%- include ('../partials/head') %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <%- include ('../partials/form') %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```