# Bootstrap float right class not working. Button not responding

Tags: css, node.js, express, bootstrap-4, ejs

I am presently practising some stuff in expressJS and EJS rendering. I noticed that Bootstrap float-right class is not working on the navbar. I even tried d-flex but the result still remain the same. I don't if I am probably doing something wrong. Below is my code:

_header.ejs

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-success">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/urls">TinyApp</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
      aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/urls">URLs</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/urls/new">New URL</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <li class="flaot-right">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-danger me-2">
            Logout
          </button>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

This is the button I tried to float to the right

```
<li class="flaot-right">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger me-2">
        Logout
    </button>
</li>
```

Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put `float-right` to the button and set the `li` tag class to standard (bootstrap 4) `nav-item` class. Additional we set `float-right` not  `flaot-right` you have a typo ;-)
Second proposition to set button on the right side is set `d-flex` and `flex-row-reverse` to `li` class like this:

```
<li class="nav-item d-flex flex-row-reverse">
```

The code is commented in `html` code snippet below, You can simple switch if you like second proposition, but remember to remove `float-right` from button ;-) Good Luck!

---

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, float vs d-flex Bootstrap 4!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-success">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/urls">TinyApp</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/urls">URLs</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/urls/new">New URL</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!--           <li class="nav-item d-flex flex-row-reverse"> -->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger me-2 float-right">
              Logout
            </button>
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did what you suggested bu it still remains the- same.

Comment: @AbubakarOluyinka have you installed bootstrap in your project ? npm install bootstrap... Did you run the code snippet above? Are you satisfied ?

Comment: I ran the code above. I removed the old one completely and I have bootstrap CDN in my project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501589/how-to-include-bootstrap-file-in-my-ejs-files