# How to access bootstrap files with EJS and Express without changing the file structure?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, npm, ejs

Just started learning NodeJS. I am using EJS to include common views and using express.static() for the public directory and pulling "style.css" from there. I was using bootstrap from CDN but now I need to do some changes on the variables such as primary color etc.

I want to keep my file structure as;

```
|-- node_modules/
|   |-- bootstrap
|   |   |
|   |   |--bootstrap stuff
|   |
|   |--other stuff
|
|-- public/
|   |-- css/
|   |   |-- style.css
|   |
|   |-- resources/
|
|-- views/
|   |-- partials
|   |   |--head.ejs
|   |
|   |--pages 
|      |--index.ejs  
|
|-- app.js
|-- package.json
|-- package-lock.json
```

I want to stop using CDN Bootstrap and link the bootstrap file that I installed via npm. How do I reach the bootstrap stuff under node_modules?

Here is also my "app.js";

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// use res.render to load up an ejs view file

// index page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('pages/index');
});

// about page
app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  res.render('pages/about');
});

// static pages for css and etc.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server is listening at '+ PORT));
```

I am aware that similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501589/how-to-include-bootstrap-file-in-my-ejs-files) but solutions were using it from different directories or from cdn.

Answer (score 0):

serve the desired folder as static, on a specific route:

```
app.use('/mycdn', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap')));
```

and then point resources to load from that route:

```
href="/mycdn/style.css"
```